# How is it possible to find the Fourier transform of unit impulse function?

Tags: fourier-transform, homework

Since Fourier transforms are applicable to only periodic functions, and unit impulse function{..0,0,1,0,0..} doesn't seem periodic, is this possible?

Is it like we are considering unit impulse function to be periodic in the range $(-\infty,+\infty)$?

Comment: The Fourier *series* is only applicable to periodic functions. The Fourier *transform* is applicable to absolute integrable functions.

Comment: And then in what sense, does the function transform from time domain to frequency domain?

Comment: I'm just realizing that you wrote *unit* impulse. Does that mean that you're asking about the *discrete* Fourier transform?

Comment: Frequency domain representation does not necessarily have to represent anything periodic.  Perhaps you are surprised that periodic basis functions are capable of such.